# Lowest energy use, 240v or 12v

Tags: inverter

I am fitting a heating system to my boat and want to know which of these two systems will use less energy from my 12v batteries. System one is a heating unit which uses 190 watts at 240v through an inverter, and system two is a heating unit which uses 72 watts at 12v direct from the battery bank. Many thanks.

Comment: There will be inefficiencies in the inverter, but as it's electric heating it doesn't really matter, all of the energy will become heat, unless the inverter is located somewhere you don't wish to heat.

Comment: The 72 W system will use less energy per unit time, but will need to be on longer to achieve the same heat gain.

Comment: neither 72W nor 190W are going to keep you warm on a boat. Suggest warm clothes, or a gas-fired heater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 72W DC system will use 72 watts from your batteries, and deliver 72 watts to where the heater is sited.

The 190W AC system will use somewhere north of 190W from your batteries, maybe 220W, deliver 190W to where the heater is, and 30W to where the inverter is. If you're careful with layout, you can make the inverter deliver its waste heat to the place you want heated as well.

Either way, that's not much heat for a boat. I suggest you get a gas fired heater.

Comment: Or diesel if that's what runs the engine, or paraffin/kerosene otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> which of these two systems will use less energy from my 12v batteries

72 watts means that the energy usage is 72 joules per second. 190 watts is 190 joules per second. Given that the "joule" is the SI unit for energy you should be able to figure which has the lower energy usage. Additionally the inverter might waste 30 watts in the voltage conversion from 12 volts to 240 volts.

So the 72 watt scenario will draw 6 amps from a 12 volt battery and the 190 watt (plus 30 watts-ish) scenario will draw about 18 or 19 amps from the 12 volt battery.

Comment: Using it for heating though, that 30 W from the inverter is a bonus :)

Comment: @Colin__s About enough to boil an egg in an hour!

Comment: hi, the 190watts/72watts is the amount of power needed to run the diesel powered heating unit, i just wanted to know whether there is more draw on the batteries using 240v via the inverter or 12v direct from the batteries as the 240v system will use less amps (i think)

Comment: @rconnan 190 W at 240 V is indeed less current than 72 W at 12 V. But, you're interested in power, the 190 W system will still be pulling 190 W (+ inverter losses) from the batteries, which will be more current than the 72 W system. Power is the product of current and voltage.

Comment: @rconnan: just curious why you are asking if 72 is a smaller number than 190?  It should be incredibly obvious which draws less power.